# Trying to pass a JS Array to a PHP script via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a `javascript array` to a `php` script using `JQuery load()`.

This is my `JQuery`:

```
$('#saveBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get hidden field values and store in an Array
    $tagArray = [];

    //Get the Checked Tags and store in an Array
    $('#tag_results :checked').each(function(){
          $tagArray.push(this.value);
    });

    //Make Ajax request to the add_tags script and pass Array as parameter. When response recieved show dialog. 
    //Pass the name, id and type of company with the array of tags to the save_tags.php script. 
    $('#test').load('pages/ajax/save_tags.php', {'tags': JSON.stringify($tagArray) ,'name': $('#comp_name').val(), 'id': $('#comp_id').val(), 'type': $('#type').val() });
});
```

I then access the `POST` Array from my `php script`:

```
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $type = $_POST['type'];
     $tags = $_POST['tags']; //Should be an Array but is a String...

     //Type can be company, contact, column, supplement, programme. 
     if($type === 'company'){
         $company = new DirectoryCompany($id);
     }

     //Loop through the Tag array and add to the item. 
     foreach($tags as $tag){
         $company->addTag($tag, $id);    
     }
```

However  when I do a `var_dump($tags)` I'm told it is a `String`, not an `Array` and as a result I get an error when I pass `$tags` to the `foreach` loop. I know that an array should be in a key value pair format when passing via POST but I'm not entirely sure how I can do that, I thought by converting it to `JSON` before passing it would do the trick but it still isn't working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `$_POST['tags']` is encoded with JSON also, its converted into string.

in php you can use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$tags = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['tags']));
```

This way, you get your required array.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get an array.

Answer (score 0):

`$tagsArray` is already in JSON format.

Just make the request like this

```
$("#test").load("pages/ajax/save_tags.php", {
    "tags": $tagArray ,
    "name": $("#comp_name").val(), 
    "id": $("#comp_id").val(), 
    "type": $("#type").val() 
});
```